# Signing and verifying a file using GnuPG

Tags: digital-signature, pgp, gnupg, openpgp

I created an RSA signing key using GnuPG.

I have few files and I want to sign these files and store online.

I signed these using GnuPG. If the original file is a.txt, GnuPG created a 1 KB file with the extension .pgp, which holds the signature.

I want to know how to verify the original a.txt using GnuPG.

I tried this:

1. Right-clicked GnuPG option and selected: "Verify"
2. On click of Verify, GnuPG throws error: "Not an OpenPGP or S/MIME signature".

I assumed GnuPG will ask about 1 kb .pgp file and will verify.

How to verify the original file correctly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@Samuel,

I figured out the problem. When signing using GPG4win, it is generating signature file with extension .pgp. I renamed this to .sig.

Now when I right-click on context menu and select "Decrypt and Verify", it is verifying the original file against this signature.

What I am not following is why GPG4win is creating signature file with extension .pgp.

Answer (score 0):

You can verify files using

1. `gpg --verify file` assuming the public key is in the keychain *and the signature (.sig usually) file is in the same directory*
2. `gpg --decrypt file` assuming the public key is in the keychain *and the file is **signed** using `gpg --sign`*

You're probably looking for the second option.

Comment: But there is no public key. I generated a signing key and it generated only one private key.

Comment: Signing is the opposite of encrypting in PGP context. You sign it with your private key, **so the public key is needed to decrypt [verify in this context] the data**.

Comment: Ok. But when using GPG4Win, I right-click file and select verify. It throws error and that is obvious. The file is not encrypted and the signature is in a separate file.

Comment: @RPK I don't really understand what you've done. Can you share the 2 files?

Comment: Found solution. Posted below as answer.